# Why when I open Terminal(On pycahrm) shows (base) not (venv)?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, python-venv

I'm setting up my server.In web application.

I'm on Windows. I have tried so many methods, when I write `python manage.py runserver`:

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file o
r directory
```

---

```
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'BlediShop.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

```
" python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory "
```

Comment: What does the question in the title has to do with the question in the description?

Comment: Make sure you're running the `python manage.py runserver` command from the directory where that file is located. For Django projects, PyCharm will often open the terminal by default in the parent directory of the one containing `manage.py`, so change the folder and try again.